# change html text based on date......JS

Tags: javascript

```
let date= new Date()

let day = date.getDay()

let weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

changeText = () => {

 if(day === 1){
   firstDay.textContent = weekday[2]
   secondDay.textContent = weekday[3]
   thirdDay.textContent = weekday[4]
   fourthDay.textContent = weekday[5]
   fifthDay.textContent = weekday[6]

 }else if(day === 2){
    firstDay.textContent = weekday[3]
    secondDay.textContent = weekday[4]
    thirdDay.textContent = weekday[5]
    fourthDay.textContent = weekday[6]
    fifthDay.textContent = weekday[0]
}
}
 changeText();
```

this is for a weather app. I need to change the html text.content based on the current day so that the extended forecast stays accurate

This code repeats for each day of the week it works but seems very inefficient. the purpose is to change the text in my html so the extended weather forecast is consistent

Comment: You could use a (`for` or `while`)  loop rolling over the `0` index and stopping when `day` is reached again. Just an idea, I am not an expert for javascript. But you should also give more detail what's your code exactly trying to achieve in the context to improve your question. Also the title needs improvement particularly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
changeText = () => {
    firstDay.textContent = weekday[(day + 1) % 7]
    secondDay.textContent = weekday[(day + 2) % 7]
    thirdDay.textContent = weekday[(day + 3) % 7]
    fourthDay.textContent = weekday[(day + 4) % 7]
    fifthDay.textContent = weekday[(day + 5) % 7]
}
```

Also I'd recommend passing `day` as a parameter. Just so that it's more clear.